# What prestashop web service http HEAD returns

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest, prestashop, httpwebresponse

I'm developing a class that operates with the prestashop web service.
And I have a problem now because I don't know what a HEAD request actually gets back from prestashop webservice...

This is my code:

```
#region HEAD
public string Head() {
    string requestURL = WebServiceURL + "/" + Table + "/" + TableID;
    WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(requestURL);
    wr.Method = "HEAD";
    wr.ContentType = "application/xml";
    wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, PassWord);
    try {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) wr.GetResponse();
        return response.Headers.ToString();
    }catch(Exception) { return ""; }
} 
#endregion
```

which return this:

```
Vary: Host
Access-Time: 1391506047
PSWS-Version: 1.5.6.1
Execution-Time: 0.011
Content-Sha1: ...
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 09:27:26 GMT
Set-Cookie: ....; httponly
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By: PrestaShop Webservice
```

**Now my question is, if this is the correct way of getting the HEAD data from the prestashop webservice and if this data is right?**

Thx :)

Comment: What for do you need HEAD request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data looks OK.

I wouldn't use `Content-Type` header in your code, because HEAD is similar to GET and sends no message body in a request even in a response, only the header data is submitted back to the client.

Check [HTTP Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).